# Images disappear in SliderView and ListView while scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp-xaml

I have a SliderView (of AppStudio.Uwp.Controls). The images appear as soon as I load the page but disappear when I scroll through the list. I tested this with a ListView too. Same thing is happening there too.

```
        <controls:SliderView x:Name="sliderView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind listForOtherPicturesThumbnails}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Hero}"
                     RelativePanel.Below="mainImage"
                     RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                     RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                     ArrowsVisibility="Visible"
                     />
```

The ItemTemplate used is as follows-

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Hero" x:DataType="local:StorageItemThumbnailClass">
        <Grid Margin="6" Padding="12" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
            <Image Source="{x:Bind Thumbnail, Converter={StaticResource ThumbnailtoImageConverter}}" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Thumbnails are produced as follows in the OnNavigated function-

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        otherPicturesPathList = ((PictureWithList)e.Parameter).pathList;

        await PopulateListOfOtherPicturesThumbnailsAsync();

        Bindings.Update();
    }

    private async Task PopulateListOfOtherPicturesThumbnailsAsync()
    {
        if (otherPicturesPathList != null)
        {
            List<Task<StorageItemThumbnail>> thumbnailOperations = new List<Task<StorageItemThumbnail>>();

            foreach (var path in otherPicturesPathList)
            {
                var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
                thumbnailOperations.Add(storageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 100).AsTask());
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(thumbnailOperations);

            for (int k = 0; k < thumbnailOperations.Count; k++)
            {
                var task = thumbnailOperations[k];
                listForOtherPicturesThumbnails.Add(new StorageItemThumbnailClass { Thumbnail = task.Result });
            }
        }
    }
```

Thumbnail to image converter-

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        BitmapImage image = null;
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.GetType() != typeof(StorageItemThumbnail))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Expected a thumbnail");
            }
            StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = (StorageItemThumbnail)value;
            image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(thumbnail);
        }
        return (image);
    }
```

StorageItemThumbnailClass-

```
public class StorageItemThumbnailClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private StorageItemThumbnail _thumbnail;
    private string _name;

    public StorageItemThumbnail Thumbnail
    {
        get { return _thumbnail; }
        set
        {
            _thumbnail = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged("Thumbnail");
        }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

}
```

How to fix this issue so that the images remain as they are seen when the page is first loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled on exactly the same problem.
The solution is to add `thumbnail.Seek(0);` in your `ThumbnailtoImageConverter`.

```
//...
StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = (StorageItemThumbnail)value;
thumbnail.Seek(0);
image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(thumbnail);
```

RefLink: [Images disappear in SliderView and ListView while scrolling](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsapps/en-US/d2c35fac-9350-4521-be2c-125eef09724d/images-disappear-in-sliderview-and-listview-while-scrolling?forum=wpdevelop)

Answer (score 0):

I can't test your code, but two suggestions:

- have you tried to set a breakpoint inside the Converter?
- give a look to the Output panel of Visual Studio, maybe you can get some information about your problem
- replace your code with this:

`thumbnailOperations.Add(await storageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 100));`

Imho something is wrong with async/await pattern.

Comment: Nothing significant is being shown in the Output panel. Your code doesn't make sense. `StorageItemThumbnail` from `await storageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 100)` cannot be converted to `Task<StorageItemThumbnail>` (type of thumbnailOperations list).

Comment: But considering that you want me to run each thumbnail operation sequentially instead of running them parallely, I've tried `listForOtherPicturesThumbnails.Add(new StorageItemThumbnailClass { Thumbnail = await storageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 100) });`. Even that didn't work.